# WritingAnimation freezes UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I'm trying to make a WritingAnimator but it freezes the UI when I run it...
Here is what I did :

```
public partial class Tsia : Form
{
    [...]

    private void TypeText()
    {
        WritingAnimator("Some text");
        WritingAnimator("This is another text");
    }

    private void WritingAnimator(string text)
    {
        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            TextBox1.AppendText(c.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

So I searched on Google and I found a way to avoid freezing the UI by using other threads :

```
public partial class Tsia : Form
{
    [...]

    private void TypeText()
    {
        WritingAnimator("Some text");
        WritingAnimator("This is another text");
    }

    private async void WritingAnimator(string text)
    {
        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            TextBox1.AppendText(c.ToString());
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
    }
}
```

But it types something like a mix of "Some text" and "This is another text" beacause WritingAnimator("This is another text"); don't wait for the end of WritingAnimator("Some text"); ...

How could I fix it ?

Comment: You need to call it with `await`, and don't use `async void`.

Comment: So my code below isn't good ?

Comment: `async` is not the same thing as multi-threaded.

Comment: So how can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Tsia : Form
{
    [...]

    private async Task TypeText()
    {
        await WritingAnimator("Some text");
        await WritingAnimator("This is another text");
    }

    private async Task WritingAnimator(string text)
    {
        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            TextBox1.AppendText(c.ToString());
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
    }
}
```

> "So I searched on Google and I found a way to avoid freezing the UI by
>   using other threads"

`await` / `async` is a **C# language feature** since version 5 and `Task.Delay` is a method which is part of the **Task Parallel Library (TPL)**. The whole TPL + async/await features simplify the usage of asynchrony for developers.

Two more thoughts:

- Maybe you want to provide a `CancellationToken` in case the user wants to stop the animation.
- There is also a [naming convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) regarding methods with async modifiers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I tried it but it's just the same result that for what I did in my second code.

Comment: As one comment already suggested, the problem is that you don't call WritingAnimator using await - This is the root cause of the unwanted behavior - If your code is still not working, there is another issue which is out of bounds regarding your code snippet